# Recommendation between native ActionBar and ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to use an ActionBar for Android 4.0+ (API 14 and above).
Do you recommend still use ActionBarSherlock, the support library or the native library?
What's the difference between ActionBarSherlock and native ActionBar in Android 4.0+?
Thanks

Comment: Read some more about that on the official Android blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not supporting older devices, there's no reason to use a compatibility surrogate.
I'd go for the native library.
So, not to add extra weight to my app and take advantage of what I already have.

In the other hand, if and external library would offer so many extra features, I could consider it.

Better if it's open source, so that I can cut off all the features I'm not interested in.

Comment: I thought ActionBarSherlock added new features regarding to native ActionBar.

Comment: I don't know anything yet about Sherlock/ActionBars, since until now I'm making FullScreen apps and use a standard menu (and, yes, I do provide a special icon for those devices which don't have a physical menu button). I must study this question for my future apps. So my answer is very generic and applies case to case (Native objects or 3rd party libraries?)